Trying to create a Github action that auto lints and formats the changed code in a PR
I have two Github actions one for auto formating and another for linting:
Auto lint
name: Lint changed files

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

jobs:
  auto_lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
    steps:
      - name: Start checkout action
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v4'
      
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: 'actions/setup-node@v4'
        with:
          node-version: 20

      - name: Setup pnpm
        uses: 'pnpm/action-setup@v4'
        with:
          version: 8

      - name: Get changed files
        id: changed-files
        uses: 'tj-actions/changed-files@v44'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install
        
      - name: Lint all changed files
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
        env:
          ALL_CHANGED_FILES: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}
        run: |
          for file in ${ALL_CHANGED_FILES}; do
            pnpm lint:check $file
          done
          
      - name: No changes to lint
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.any_changed != 'true'
        run: echo "No changes files to lint"

Auto format
name: Format changed files

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

jobs:
  auto_format:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
    steps:
      - name: Start checkout action
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v4'
      
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: 'actions/setup-node@v4'
        with:
          node-version: 20

      - name: Setup pnpm
        uses: 'pnpm/action-setup@v4'
        with:
          version: 8

      - name: Get changed files
        id: changed-files
        uses: 'tj-actions/changed-files@v44'
        
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install
        
      - name: format all changed files
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
        env:
          ALL_CHANGED_FILES: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}
        run: |
          for file in ${ALL_CHANGED_FILES}; do
            pnpm format:fix $file
          done

          git config user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git add .
          git commit -m "style: auto format"
          git push     
      - name: No changes to format
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.any_changed != 'true'
        run: echo "No changes files to format"

When running these two with Act and github actions they fail with the error:
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ]   ✅  Success - Main Install dependencies
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ] ⭐ Run Main Get changed files
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/changed-files] user= workdir=
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ]   ✅  Success - Main Get changed files
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ] ⭐ Run Main Create lint script for changed files
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/5] user= workdir=
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ]   ✅  Success - Main Create lint script for changed files
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ] ⭐ Run Main Run linter on changed files
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/6] user= workdir=
| ./lint.sh: line 1: No: command not found
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ]   ❌  Failure - Main Run linter on changed files
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ] exitcode '127': command not found, please refer to https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/107 for more information
[Lint Changed Files/Lint Changed Files            ]   Job failed

[run-tests/format changed files                   ]   ❓  ::endgroup::
[run-tests/format changed files                   ]   ❓ add-matcher /run/act/actions/actions-setup-node@v4/.github/tsc.json
[run-tests/format changed files                   ]   ❓ add-matcher /run/act/actions/actions-setup-node@v4/.github/eslint-stylish.json
[run-tests/format changed files                   ]   ❓ add-matcher /run/act/actions/actions-setup-node@v4/.github/eslint-compact.json
[run-tests/format changed files                   ]   ✅  Success - Main actions/setup-node@v4
[run-tests/format changed files                   ]   ⚙  ::set-output:: node-version=v20.14.0
[run-tests/format changed files                   ]   ⚙  ::add-path:: /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.14.0/arm64/bin
[run-tests/format changed files                   ] ⭐ Run Main actions/checkout@v4
[run-tests/format changed files                   ]     docker cp src=/Users/ekrich/git/eTech-UI/. dst=/Users/ekrich/git/eTech-UI
| npm error code ENOTEMPTY
| npm error syscall rename
| npm error path /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.14.0/arm64/lib/node_modules/pnpm
| npm error dest /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.14.0/arm64/lib/node_modules/.pnpm-i4BzBorb
| npm error errno -39
| npm error ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.14.0/arm64/lib/node_modules/pnpm' -> '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.14.0/arm64/lib/node_modules/.pnpm-i4BzBorb'
| 
| npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-06-08T03_31_06_800Z-debug-0.log
[Autoformat Changed Files/Autoformat Changed Files]   ❌  Failure - Main Install pnpm
[Autoformat Changed Files/Autoformat Changed Files] exitcode '217': failure
[Autoformat Changed Files/Autoformat Changed Files]   Job failed
[run-tests/format changed files                   ]   ✅  Success - Main actions/checkout@v4
[run-tests/format changed files                   ] ⭐ Run Main pnpm install

Any idea what is wrong here? Is there a pre-made action I can use instead? I've tried using actions/changed-files but that doesn't work either.
Refrences I've looked at but still had no luck in:

Get modified files in Github actions
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-auto-format


Not an answer, but: please update your action versions. You're probably getting warnings from GH Actions telling you Node 16 is deprecated. You should use actions/checkout@v4 and actions/setup-node@v4 rather than the older versions you have.

An additional non-answer bit of advice: have you considered using husky pre-commit hooks instead of doing this in CI? Our JS/TS projects use husky in such a way that all these formatting changes are done in each dev's machine during the commit process, so we don't have to do it in CI. Although sometimes devs bypass these, so I understand the value of also doing it in CI. Come to think of it, it's tempting to borrow your idea and add something equivalent to our workflows!

@joanis Thanks for the advice! I actually already have husky pre-commit hooks in my project to handle this. However this is going to be an open source project meaning these hooks could easily be bypassed. If you manage to get my idea working in your project please share the implementation :)

Well, no promises I'll write this any time soon, but if I do I'll try to remember to report back here.

Although in one Python project I went much cruder than this: in my regular test workflow, I added find . -name \*.py | xargs black --check to just reject any commit/PR that has any file that doesn't pass our formatter.

OK, just added a solution that should work for you. xargs is your friend!

Thanks for the help. I have decied to refactor my action and will consider your answer in the new action.

@joanis I finished refactoring the actions and have added the changes to my question. However, now when running the new actions I'm getting an error with eslint because it is still formating the files specified to ignore in .gitignore any reason for this?

If files listed in .gitignore are checked in CI, they have to be in your repo. Did you accidentally add them before listing them in .gitignore?

@joanis Initialy that was the case. However after removing all of the files that were in the gitignore and are no longer on the remote remote I'm still getting a bunch of warnings on .nx/cache/cloud/2405.31.4.hotfix6/index.js which is both in the gitignore and is no longer on the remote.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Diagnostic
For the lint, the problem is that what you created is not a proper script.
The line
echo "No JavaScript or TypeScript files were changed." > lint.sh

is what ends up having been run, based on the error message ./lint.sh: line 1: No: command not found, and indeed, you've created script lint.sh with the contents
No JavaScript or TypeScript files were changed.

which is definitely not a valid script.
General recommendation
The way you're trying to create a script inside the action is really not ideal. The solution I would recommend is to write your lint.sh and format.sh scripts locally, where you can test them easily until they work on your own machine. Put the loop over changed files right in there. Then add those scripts to your repo and just call them in the action workflow, passing in the changed_files.txt file as an argument.
A more precise solution
This should work for you, instead of the Create format script for changes files and Run formatter on changed files steps:
      - name: Run formatter on changed files of interest
        run: cat changed_files.txt | grep -E '\.(js|ts|tsx|cjs|mjs|astro|spec.ts|mdx)$' | xargs --no-run-if-empty pnpm run format --

And for the linter, replace format by lint:check.
Explanation:

grep the list of changed files for the extensions you care about
pass the results as argument to your pnpm command
use xargs's --no-run-if-empty option to avoid calling pnpm with an empty list of files

